# Paypal IPN Variables PHP

Tags: php, html, paypal, paypal-ipn

Hi I'm working on setting up the ipn but i'm very very new to php and what not I thought I had it figured out but wasn't even close :)

Anyway all i'm looking to do is after a payment is made write the persons name in a text file and then next to that just write their input in the text field i made in my button which looks like this

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="5ES3TSKJNLJ24">
<table style="text-align: right; width: 100%;">
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Amount you'd like to donate">Amount you'd like to donate</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="Just the license">Just the license $2.99 USD</option>
    <option value="A bit more">A bit more $5.99 USD</option>
    <option value="Two bits more">Two bits more $8.99 USD</option>
    <option value="A lot more">A lot more $15.00 USD</option>
    <option value="We love you :)">We love you :) $50.00 USD</option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Primary Phone Gmail">Primary Phone Gmail</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" align="right" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

my ipn.php looks like this

```
<?php
// Revision Notes
// 11/04/11 - changed post back url from https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr to https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
// For more info see below:
// https://www.x.com/content/bulletin-ip-address-expansion-paypal-services
// "ACTION REQUIRED: if you are using IPN (Instant Payment Notification) for Order Management and your IPN listener script is behind a firewall that uses ACL (Access Control List) rules which restrict outbound traffic to a limited number of IP addresses, then you may need to do one of the following: 
// To continue posting back to https://www.paypal.com  to perform IPN validation you will need to update your firewall ACL to allow outbound access to *any* IP address for the servers that host your IPN script
// OR Alternatively, you will need to modify  your IPN script to post back IPNs to the newly created URL https://ipnpb.paypal.com using HTTPS (port 443) and update firewall ACL rules to allow outbound access to the ipnpb.paypal.com IP ranges (see end of message)."


// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate

$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";

    // If testing on Sandbox use: 
    // $header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com:443\r\n";
$header .= "Host: ipnpb.paypal.com:443\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    // If testing on Sandbox use:
    //$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://ipnpb.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$payer_firstName = $_POST['first_name'];
$payer_lastName = $_POST['last_name'];
$gmail = $_POST['on1'];

//set email variables
$From_email = "From: fake@website.com";
$Subject_line = "Thanks for your purchase";

$email_msg = "\n\nThe details of your order are as follows:";
$email_msg .= "\n\n" . "Transaction ID: " .  $txn_id ;
$email_msg .= "\n" . "Payment Date: " . $payment_date;

if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
// check the payment_status is Completed
// check that txn_id has not been previously processed
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
// check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
// process payment

$mail_From = $From_email;
$mail_To = $payer_email;
$mail_Subject = $Subject_line;
$mail_Body = $email_msg;

mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);

$data = "$payer_firstName $payer_lastName $gmail";

$fh = fopen("./paypal/test.txt", "a");
fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh);

}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation

$mail_From = $From_email;
$mail_To = $receiver_email;
$mail_Subject = "INVALID IPN POST";
$mail_Body = "INVALID IPN POST. The raw POST string is below.\n\n" . $req;

mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);

}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you checking for magic quotes? This option has been deprecated and nobody should be using it. This adds extra complexity to your code.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the example from paypal i honestly don't know much php which is why i'm having trouble lol. The extend of my php knowledge is writing a text file :)

Comment: updated my question a bit hopefully that's more simple all i'm trying to do is after they pay just write their name and the input of the text field on a line in a txt file on my server.

Comment: Alright well my ipn is now successful but when i actually run it with a real transaction using my script above it doesn't send the email or write to that text file which does exist any ideas? I think i'm close i'm just not seeing it working right and in my advanced variables i have notify_url=http://www.website.com/ipn.php which i've also checked and exists but it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already figured it out got it all up and running took me all day (got it working at 3:40am) but did learn a lot of php in a day ha i'll post what i did in a few

Comment: Could you maybe enlighten us as to how you solved this problem? At the moment this answer doesn't really help anyone else who may have the same problem. If you do that then I'll re-open your question. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry this is an old question when I was real new to code and the website but yea I remember following this tutorial http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html and was able to get it hooked up and working. Main point though is on paypal's website you need to point the button towards the ipn script